# Improve basic script to preload images

Tags: javascript, image

I want to preload a dozen or so images used on various pages of my website – so that by the time a user opens a page, the image that is included in it opens instantly.

To achieve this, I placed the following script inside the  tag:

```
<script>

if (document.images) {
var my_image_one = new Image();
my_image_one.src= "path/to/images/my-image-one.jpg";
var my_image_two = new Image();
my_image_two.src= "path/to/images/my-image-two.jpg";
var my_image_three = new Image();
my_image_three.src= "path/to/images/my-image-three.jpg";

/* etc. */

</script>
```

Problems I see with the script:

1. It's repetitive.
2. It runs, and therefore tries to load the images
       every time any new page loads (even if the images had already been
       loaded).

I want to improve it, creating something like this:

```
if (document.images) {
my_images = array (image_name=>path/to/image/image-name.jpg, et cetera);
for (i=1;i++;i<=array.length) {
if "the image hasn't been preloaded yet" {
preload image;
} 
}
```

How can this be translated into proper JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an array of strings like this:

```
var paths = [ "first/path", "second/path", "third/path" ];
```

As to worrying about redundant loads, don't - the browser will figure that out. That's the whole point of the cache.

If you're doing this work at a point in your page such that `document.images` is already set, then there's no point doing it at all unless your list of images is comprehensive for a multi-page site. For a single page, the browser will have parsed the DOM and seen all your `<img>` tags by that time, and so it will already be loading the images. Preloading images just for the page you're on is probably not worthwhile in general. It's useful to do from a "Welcome" introductory page on a big multi-page site so that subsequent pages render quickly.

Comment: It is a big multi-page site, @Pointy.

Comment: @Figaro well ok then :-) It'd probably be a good idea to defer the preload until the window "load" event, so that the HTTP requests for all the images on other pages don't get in the way of things needed for the initial page.